# Python Script not Running in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, python-2.7, command-line, terminal, atom-editor

I type `print “hello world”` in my atom text editor then in my Mac OS X terminal I run `cd /users/my user/myfolder` then i run the file I was writing`python example.py`
After that my Mac does nothing. No error message, no nothing it just goes to a new line

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file before executing it?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error message and no printing, you probably did not include a output command in your python file, such as `print`.

Run this command in your terminal and it will work:

`echo "print \"hello world\"" >> example.py`

then `python example.py`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this. The editor u used add only LF at the end of the line.
Try to save it as Unix file or add LFCR for carrier return. It should solve the problem.

Of course, run python first and see python is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It's the text editor Atom. You have to add LFCR as the last line of the code. I spent an hour trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the beginning of your code to remove the issue for LFCR .

```
print("\n\r")
```